# MySQL order by query with a group by subquery

Tags: php, mysql

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT bid.bidID, bid.bidJobID, 
bid.bidVanManID, bid.bidMemberID, bid.bidAmount, 
van.vanmanCompanyName, van.vanmanUsername,
job.jobID, job.acceptedQuote FROM bids bid 
JOIN vanman van 
ON 
bidVanManID = van.vanmanID 
JOIN jobs job 
ON
bidJobID = job.jobID WHERE bidJobID = ? AND bidMemberID = ?");
```

Currently, it selects all bids from the bid table and joins the vanman table to retrieve the vanman details for each bid.

Duplicate vanman are being returned (which is fine, as I allow up to 3 bids per vanman, so it's expected)

However, I'm wanting to remove duplicate bid's from the same vanman, leaving only the most recent bid (bidTime)

I've tried a subquery on the JOIN vanman to select distinct, however, my MySQL knowledge is limited to somewhat basic queries.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT bid.bidID, MAX(bid.bidTime), bid.bidJobID, 
bid.bidVanManID, bid.bidMemberID, bid.bidAmount, 
van.vanmanCompanyName, van.vanmanUsername,
job.jobID, job.acceptedQuote FROM bids bid 
JOIN vanman van 
ON 
bidVanManID = van.vanmanID 
JOIN jobs job 
ON
bidJobID = job.jobID WHERE bidJobID = ? AND bidMemberID = ?
GROUP BY vanmanID ORDER BY bidTime DESC");
```

The above works by removing the duplicates now, as I did achieve before, but it doesn't leave the one with the latest bidTime

Comment: I'm aware I currently don't have bidTime selected but I have tried many attempts to achieve what I'm aiming for to no avail, so have reverted back to my working model (albeit with duplicates)

Comment: to get the latest date use max(bidTime)

Comment: I tried that, but then strangely only 1 row is being returned. I want all rows to be returned, just removing duplicates.

I tried adding max(bidTime) and also GROUP BY vanmanID - which then actually works, but the row that is left of the duplicates is NOT the latest one (I tried MIN(bidTime after to no avail)

Comment: @caryaritferrer